# primeNG pre set value is not working, it shows as [object object]

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular2-forms, primeng, angular4-forms

I'm using a prime-NG drop-down with angular 4, belove I have mentioned important parts of my code. after I selected a drop-down item I save this "config.value" value in database. the problem occurs when I open this form again, I want to show selected dropdown item as selected . so i query the db and set "config.value" to saved item. but then dropdown shows it as [object object] . how should I change my code to fix this problem.

html :

```
  <p-dropdown [options] = "options" 
              [(ngModel)] = "config.value" 
              editable = true
              optionsLabel = "label"
              [formControlName] = "config.name" 
              [placeholder] = "config.label" 
              [filter] = "config.options['filter']">
  </p-dropdown>
```

.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.getOptions( this.orgId )
    .subscribe( result =>{
      if (result[0]){
        for (let i =0; i < result.length ; i++){
          this.options.push({label: result[i].name, value: result[i] })
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

result which return from service:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Sachithra",
        "phone"  : "xxxxxxxxx",
        "addreess": "yyyyyyyyy A" 
    },
    {
        "name": "wishwamal",
        "phone"  : "xxxxxxxxx",
        "addreess": "yyyyyyyy B" 
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you fill the `options` variable, you should set a value to the property called `value`. Here, you are setting an object :

```
this.options.push({label: result[i].name, value: result[i] })
```

Try something like this instead :

```
this.options.push({label: result[i].name, value: result[i].phone })
```

or

```
this.options.push({label: result[i].name, value: result[i].addreess })
```